# Hola tengo problema con una pagina de WordPress al ejecutar una función en el archivo functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Buen día, soy nuevo en esto de wordpress.
actualice unos pluggins, wordpress a la version 6.6.2 y Php versión 8.1 pero después de la actualizacion la pagina comenzó a tener varios problemas pude solucionar algunos pero este me tiene atorado. Active el depurador para ver el error y muestra esto:

> Error fatal : error no detectado: llamada a la función indefinida create_function() en /home/sistema/public_html/wp-content/themes/amcp/functions.php:486 Rastreo de pila: #0 /home/sistema/public_html/wp-settings. php(591): include() #1 /inicio/sistema/public_html/wp-config.php(91): require_once('/inicio/sistema...') #2 /inicio/sistema/public_html/wp-load .php(50): require_once('/home/sistema...') #3 /home/sistema/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/sistema...') #4 /home/sistema/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/sistema...') #5 {main} incluido en /home/sistema/public_html/wp-content/themes/amcp/ funciones.php en la línea 486

Busque el código que genera el error y no lo comprendo muy bien, hice algunas modificaciones que busque en internet pero sin el conocimiento adecuado me fue imposible.

```html
$html5shim = create_function( '', 'echo \'<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="\'.get_template_directory_uri().\'/js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->\';' );
add_action( 'wp_head', $html5shim );
```

Estuve investigando sobre esto pero aun soy muy nuevo espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Parece ser un problema de temas y la versión de PHP. He tenido ese mismo inconveniente con algunos temas que ya no se actualizan y estaban diseñados para PHP 7. En PHP 8 se introdujo varias incompatibilidades importantes respecto a versiones anteriores. Mira las [guías de migración](https://www.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php). También, para probar, intenta colocar otro tema que esté actualizado, como los Twenty's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create_function fue eliminado en php 8, por lo que ya no puede usarse, mi recomendación es borrar esta linea.

```
$html5shim = create_function( '', 'echo \'<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="\'.get_template_directory_uri().\'/js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->\';' );
add_action( 'wp_head', $html5shim );
```

Sin embargo si aun necesita ese archivo puede encolarlo reemplazando esas líneas con esto.

```
function html5_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'html5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'html5_script' );
```

Esto encolara el script html5.js usando la funcion wp_enqueue_scripts de wordpress.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro me funciono correctamente ;) sabes si existe alguna forma de migrar una pagina web de version php

Comment: No existe tal forma, generalmente se recomiendo crear un devsite o sitio de prueba, ahi subes tu web con su version de php actualizada y haces pruebas, cualquier error que haya lo solucionas y cuando este todo bien y funcionado entonces lo pasas al live site, el sitio en produccion, pero no hay una forma automatizada de hacerlo.